# How to drop rows of dataframe inside of the function python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `dataframe` and I want to `drop` some rows inside of the function

```
def IncomeToGo(dataframe, mainCatName):
    for k in dataframe.name:
        if mainCatName in k:
            dataframe= dataframe.drop(dataframe.loc[dataframe.name == k].index)
```

this is the way I use that function

```
print(len(df1)) // len = 21

IncomeToGo(df1, 'Apple')

print(len(df1)) // len = 21
```

but the `drop` part don't do anything and nothing removed form my `dataframe`

Comment: try returning the dataframe instead of assigning

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
def IncomeToGo(dataframe, mainCatName):
    return dataframe[dataframe.name.ne(mainCatName)]
```

##### Example:

Initial df:

```
   name     menu
0     A   cheese
1     A     cake
2     A  sausage
3     B  chicken
4     B     cake
5     B    water
6     C  chicken
7     C  sausage
8     C    water
9     D    water
10    D   cheese
11    D  sausage
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'B',
  4: 'B',
  5: 'B',
  6: 'C',
  7: 'C',
  8: 'C',
  9: 'D',
  10: 'D',
  11: 'D'},
 'menu': {0: 'cheese',
  1: 'cake',
  2: 'sausage',
  3: 'chicken',
  4: 'cake',
  5: 'water',
  6: 'chicken',
  7: 'sausage',
  8: 'water',
  9: 'water',
  10: 'cheese',
  11: 'sausage'}})


def IncomeToGo(dataframe, mainCatName):
    return dataframe[dataframe.name.ne(mainCatName)]

IncomeToGo(df, 'A')
```

OUTPUT df:

```
   name     menu
3     B  chicken
4     B     cake
5     B    water
6     C  chicken
7     C  sausage
8     C    water
9     D    water
10    D   cheese
11    D  sausage
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors in your code:

1. You don't return anything from your function
2. You remove rows from the column that your are looping through. This is a very bad practice

Try just by filtering out these rows:

```
def IncomeToGo(dataframe, mainCatName):
    return dataframe[dataframe.name != mainCatName]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like below if you want to use for loop over column values

```
def IncomeToGo(dataframe, mainCatName):
    for k in dataframe.name.unique():
        if mainCatName == k:
            dataframe = dataframe.loc[dataframe.name != mainCatName].copy()
            
    return dataframe
```

I would advice not to hardcode column names in the function. Write them in such a way that function can be used at mutiple places dynamically.